# Migrating IIS Hosted .NET WebApp from Windows 2008 Server to Windows 2019 Server

Tags: .net, iis, deployment, iis-7.5

I am currently working on this issue for migrating our windows 2008 instance for our old service in AWS to Windows 2019 Server AMI. (NOT IN-PLACE) We first did this by just looking into the iis configurations for the sites and the application pools and created a chef deployment script that would download that to the 2019 Server. But the 2019 version had issues even though the software (web config), application pool settings, sites ... everything looked the same.

So next thing, I did was use web-deploy (msdeploy) to download the iis pools and sites and configs in the working 2008 Windows Server to a package and then import it using msdeploy to a clean Windows 2019 server that had dependencies ready downloaded. I was expecting that we were missing some issue with the iis configuration that is causing the issue and this would solve it. But it didn't?

**The Error I See**: The iis sites actually work in both ways (chef and the msdeploy export/import method) so that is a success in that the app isn't crashing but for some reason I see functional errors. Some of the requests return an 200 response with error message on the 2019 version that are completely fine and return a good response with data in the 2008 version even though the software and the iis configuration is the same as far as I have investigated.

Is there something I am missing?

Thanks.

Comment: “I see functional errors”, and then you need the original developers or an experienced consultant to help. This is no longer a general IIS migration issue, as Windows Server 2019 isn't Windows Server 2008 and years of changes from the operating system can impact.

Comment: In fact, for the migration between different versions of IIS, the most recommended way is to use [IIS Easy Migration Tool (IEMT)](https://www.iis.net/downloads/community/2013/04/iis-easy-migration-tool-iemt). This can simplify the migration process and reduce the occurrence of problems.